# Where to add encrypted credentials so that we can download files from IIS server

Tags: powershell

I have the following function in my script but I keep getting this error:

```
    Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server
    returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
+ $links = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,"$cp\url ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

What I need is to first authenticate with the website I'm trying to download the files from (using Windows Authentication) but I'm not sure how and where to add them in this function:

```
function DownloadFile($url, $targetFile)
{
   $uri = New-Object "System.Uri" "$url"
   $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
   $request.set_Timeout(15000) #15 second timeout
   $response = $request.GetResponse()
}
```

So I just don't know how and where exactly I need to specify the username and password and possibly domain although it's a local computer account we're using.

If I enable anonymous authentication on the IIS server then the script works but not with Windows Authentication. A text file is downloaded which contains different download links on separate lines and then we download each link.

Also it'd be nice if I didn't have to specify the credentials in the script in plain text. Hence if we use an encrypted creds.txt file then it needs to work from any computer on any network.

Comment: The [`HttpWebRequest.Credentials` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials) is where you'd specify the _plain text_ credentials (e.g. `$request.Credentials = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' -ArgumentList 'username', 'password', 'domain'`, where `'domain'` is the computer name).  You can also pass the password as a [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) instead of a `String`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it but I still get the same error. Maybe you could you provide an example using my code? Maybe I'm putting the $request.Credentials in the wrong place. Also, for encoded password do you mean this: $password = "encodedPwd" | ConvertTo-SecureString  -AsPlainText -Force ? If so how do I encode it first? I know the credentials work because if I go to the link using my browser and enter my credentials when prompted I'm able to download the files.
Using the script I get the same error if I put the $request.Credentials in or not.

Comment: I got the credentials part working and saved in an xml file. Script works fine and is able to download files but problem is it only works on my system. I need it working on every system.

Comment: As you make progress with your code you should edit that into the question.  I'm not positive but if you're using a `SecureString` I believe that might be machine-specific.  There should be other questions here that address the general issue of securely accessing encrypted credentials from multiple machines.